# Unmarshaling XML document with no namespace declarations

Tags: xml, jaxb, moxy

Given a schema that has a target namespace, such as the example shown below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://intranet.putnaminv.com/messaging" xmlns:messaging="http://intranet.putnaminv.com/messaging">
  <xs:element name="Customer">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="messaging:CustAddress"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="CustAddress">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="messaging:AddressLine"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="AddressLine" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

How do I unmarshall a XML instance that does not have any namespaces, such as this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customer>
    <CustAddress>
        <AddressLine>Address Line 1</AddressLine>
    </CustAddress>
</Customer>
```

I keep running into error:
file:/C:/customer.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 11; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Customer'

Is there anyway to be able to unmarshall this XML? While I do not have control over how the XML is generated, I can modify the schema if needed.

Thanks
Aspi

Comment: Thank you. Worked very well.